# Como atualizar um framework no iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Estou alterando um aplicativo.
Esse aplicativo utiliza um `framework` chamado `Ushahidi` que é compatível apenas com `iOS7`.
Eu detectei uma alteração para que uma coisa no `framework` funcione no `iOS8`.

Minha dúvida é como eu posso alterar o `framework` para corrigir o `bug`?
Estou pensando em fazer a correção e enviar para o github deles, mas preciso testar no aplicativo para ver se vai funcionar.

Como fazer isso!?

Comment: Assim como você mesmo disse, você pode fazer a correção para o iOS 8 e submeter um pull request no GitHub do framework, já que ele é aberto.

Comment: Sim Douglas, mas preciso testar antes para ver se está correto. A minha dificuldade é que no GitHub os arquivos .h e .m estão disponíveis, mas quando baixamos o Framework não estão.

Comment: voce ja tentou especificar a ultima versão dele no Podfile?

Comment: O Ushahidi não é um framework que você adiciona em seus projetos. Na verdade ele é um app pronto (com o framework incluído) que pode ser modificado para as suas necessidades. Na verdade eu já desisti. O processo de criação de um framework no iOS é muito penoso. Preferi criar classes e sobrescrever os comportamentos para o que eu precisava. Obrigado de qualquer forma.